# Inspec tests conditional on OS version

Tags: chef, virtualbox, inspec

What is the idiomatic way to tell Inspec to run test X on OS version A and test Y on OS version B? I'm aware of [the technique](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/accessing-chef-node-attributes-from-kitchen-tests) of dumping the Chef `node` object to a JSON file in `/tmp` but that isn't doing it for me as *that* runs within the Test Kitchen VM whereas [Inspec executes on the real host](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/ruby_usage/) and therefore can't see it.

Comment: May I ask why you run the inspec tests from test kitchen instead of during the node run with for exemple the chef-audit cookbook ? From what you describe, inspec run in a temporary VM targetting a real host, why not running inspec on the real host itself ?

Comment: Inspec on a real host targeting a temporary VM in which runs the entire run list

Comment: So turn the other way, why not running inspec within the VM ?

Comment: Because in my use cases it needs to see things that the VMs do not/cannot see

Comment: At this point you'd better [edit] your question to give more context. I highly suspect this will turn into a XY question and should be asked on #inspec channel on [chef's slack](http://community-slack.chef.io/) instead. the StackExchange format won't help much I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest, like comments under your post, is to take this to the #inspec channel on the Chef Community Slack to ask there. That said, here's how I might attack this:

```
control 'some-control-slug' do
  title 'My control'
  impact 1.0
  desc 'Example code for Stack Exchange'

  if os.windows? && ::Gem::Version.new(os.release) < ::Gem::Version.new('6.1')
    # Only executed on Windows machines older than 2008r2
    describe directory('C:/Users') do
      it { should exist }
    end

  elsif os.windows? && ::Gem::Version.new(os.release) >= ::Gem::Version.new('10')
    # Only executed on Windows Server 2016 or newer
    describe directory('D:/MyFolder') do
      it { should_not exist }
    end

  end

  # Executed on all host types
  describe sys_info do
    its('hostname') { should match(/SomeAwesomeHost/i) }
  end
end
```

Additionally, you can limit the entire inspec control with Chef-like hooks, such as `only_if`. The above example code, as written, may execute on a Linux target. We could limit all of them by placing the following up near the `desc` or `title`:

```
only_if { os.windows? }
```